# Doubt about a construction of the derivative of functions between smooth manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, smooth-manifolds

I'm reading *Definition 1.8* from this lecture [note](https://minterscompactness.files.wordpress.com/2019/01/Differential_Geometry_Part_II_Notes.pdf). Due to heavy notations, the author seems to abuse notations, making the exposition confusing to a beginner like me.

> **Definition 1.8.** Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$ and $Y \subset \mathbb{R}^{\tilde{N}}$ be (smooth) manifolds, and let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be smooth. Then the differential at $\boldsymbol{x}$ of $\boldsymbol{f}$ is the linear map $\mathrm{d} f_{x}: T_{x} X \rightarrow T_{f(x)} Y$ defined as follows:
>
> Choose local parameterisations $\varphi$ about $x$ and $\psi$ about $f(x)$ with $\varphi: U \rightarrow X, \psi: V \rightarrow Y$, and $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}, V \subset \mathbb{R}^{\tilde{n}}$ open. Then $h:=\psi^{-1} \circ f \circ \varphi: U \rightarrow V$ is a map of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{\tilde{n}}$ and so we can differentiate it.
>
> Then as $\mathrm{d} \varphi_{\varphi^{-1}(x)}$ is an isomorphism onto $\operatorname{Im}\left(\mathrm{d} \varphi_{\varphi^{-1}(x)}\right)=T_{x} X$, the map $\mathrm{d} \varphi_{\varphi^{-1}(x)}: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow T_{x} X$ is an isomorphism and so has an inverse. Then we can define:
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \mathrm{d} f_{x} &:=\mathrm{d} \psi_{\psi^{-1}(f(x))} \circ \mathrm{d} h_{\varphi^{-1}(x)} \circ\left[\left(\mathrm{d} \varphi_{\varphi^{-1}(x)}\right)^{-1}\right] \\
> &\left(=\mathrm{d} \psi_{\psi^{-1}(f(x))} \circ \mathrm{d}\left(\psi^{-1} \circ f \circ \varphi\right)_{\varphi^{-1}(x)} \circ\left[\left(\mathrm{d} \varphi_{\varphi^{-1}(x)}\right)^{-1}\right]\right)
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> which by construction is a linear map $T_{x} X \rightarrow T_{f(x)} Y$, since it is a composition of linear maps with the correct domain and image.

- The images of $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are not necessarily the whole $X$ and $Y$, but their open subsets.
- The map $h$ is not necessarily well-defined on the whole $U$. This is because $f \circ \varphi (U)$ is not necessarily a subset of $\operatorname{dom}(\varphi^{-1})$.

Could you have a check if my understanding below is correct?

---

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb R^M$ and $Y \subseteq \mathbb R^N$ be $m$- and $n$-dimensional smooth manifolds respectively. Let $f:X \to Y$ be smooth. Fix $x \in X$. Let $\varphi:U \to V$ and $\psi:A \to B$ be local parameterizations around $x$ and $f(x)$ respectively.

- The composition of smooth functions is smooth, so $f \circ \varphi: U \to Y$ is smooth. Because $B$ is open in $Y$, $U' := (f \circ \varphi)^{-1} (B)$ is open in $U$. Then $h:= \psi^{-1} \circ f \circ \varphi_{\restriction U'}: U' \to A$ is well-defined and smooth.
- Notice that $h$ is not necessarily injective, so $A$ is not necessarily its image.
- Moreover, $U$ is open in $\mathbb R^m$, so is $U'$. Hence $h$ is indeed differentiable at any point in $U'$.
- Notice that $f \circ \varphi (\varphi^{-1} (x)) = f(x) \in B$, so $\varphi^{-1} (x) \in U'$.  Hence $h$ is differentiable at $\varphi^{-1} (x)$.
- Also, the domain $U'$ of $h$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^m$, so the domain of $\mathrm d h_{\varphi^{-1} (x)}$ is $\mathbb R^m$. The codomain $A$ of $h$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^n$, so the image of $\mathrm d h_{\varphi^{-1} (x)}$ is also a subset $\mathbb R^n$, i.e., $$\mathrm d h_{\varphi^{-1} (x)}: \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n.$$

Because $\varphi$ is a diffeomorphism, $\mathrm d \varphi_{\varphi^{-1} (x)}$ is an isomorphism from $\mathbb R^m$ to $T_x X$. This implies $\mathrm d \varphi_{\varphi^{-1} (x)}$ has an inverse $$(\mathrm d \varphi_{\varphi^{-1} (x)})^{-1}: T_x X \to \mathbb R^m.$$

We also have $$\mathrm d \psi_{\psi^{-1} \circ f (x)}: \mathbb R^n \to T_{f(x)}Y.$$

Then we define the derivative of $f$ at $x$ by $$\mathrm d f_x := \mathrm d \psi_{\psi^{-1} \circ f (x)} \circ \mathrm d h_{\varphi^{-1} (x)} \circ (\mathrm d \varphi_{\varphi^{-1} (x)})^{-1}.$$

Thus we can write $$\mathrm d f_x : T_xX \to T_{f(x)}Y.$$

Notice that $\mathrm d \psi_{\psi^{-1} \circ f (x)}$ and $(\mathrm d \varphi_{\varphi^{-1} (x)})^{-1}$ are isomorphisms. As a result,

- $\mathrm d f_x$ is injective if and only if $\mathrm d h_{\varphi^{-1} (x)}$ is injective.
- $\mathrm d f_x$ is surjective if and only if $\mathrm d h_{\varphi^{-1} (x)}$ is surjective.
- $\mathrm d f_x$ is bijective if and only if $\mathrm d h_{\varphi^{-1} (x)}$ is bijective.
- $\mathrm d f_x$ is an isomorphism if and only if $\mathrm d h_{\varphi^{-1} (x)}$ is an isomorphism.

---

I recall related definitions from the note to avoid ambiguity.

- Let $U$ be **open** in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$. A map $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is **smooth** if all  of its partial derivatives of all orders exist and are continuous.
- Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{N}$, $Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $f: X \rightarrow Y$, and $x \in X$. A map $\tilde{f}: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a **smooth extension** of $f$ around $x$ if $U$ is open in $\mathbb R^N$, $x \in U$, $\tilde f$ is smooth, and $\tilde{f}$ agrees with $f$ on $U \cap X$.
- Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{N}$ and $Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$. A map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is **smooth** if $f$ has a smooth extension around any $x \in X$.
- A bijective smooth map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ with $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{N}$ and $Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a **diffeomorphism** if its inverse $f^{-1}: Y \rightarrow X$ is also smooth.
- A subset $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{N}$ is  a smooth $n$-dimensional **manifold** if $\forall x \in X$, $\exists$ a diffeomorphism $\varphi : U \to V$ such that $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $V$ is open in $X$, and $x \in V$.  Then $\varphi$ is a **local parameterization** around $x$. The inverse $\varphi^{-1}$ is a **local coordinate system** (or **chart**) around $x$.
- Let $X \subseteq \mathbb R^N$ be a smooth $n$-dimensional manifold and $x \in X$. Let $\varphi: U \to V$ be a local parameterization around $x$. The map $\mathrm d \varphi_{\varphi^{-1}(x)} : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^N$ is the Fréchet derivative of $\varphi$ at $\varphi^{-1}(x)$. The **tangent space** of $X$ at $x$, denoted by $T_xX$, is the image of $\mathrm d \varphi_{\varphi^{-1}(x)}$, i.e., $$T_xX := \operatorname{im} \left (\mathrm d \varphi_{\varphi^{-1}(x)} \right ).$$